# How to get xlsxwriter to write full list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list which I convert to a dataframe in python like so. It works but only grabs one Item and writes it. How can I fix this?

Thanks

```
for x in re.finditer(some_regex, res.html.raw_html.decode()):
    res_str = x.group()
    out_list = re.split('(\s+), res_str)
    df = pd.DataFrame(out_list)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('somefile.xlsx', 'xlsxwriter') #Only grabs one value then quits
df.to_excel(writer, 'blah')
writer.save()
```

Comment: Probably need to unindent the df = pd.DataFrame(out_list) so that it's not inside your for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by Chris above. You should to take your data frame creation out of the loop to speed up things. Otherwise you will be recreating the data frame multiple times.

```
out_list = []
for x in re.finditer(some_regex, res.html.raw_html.decode()):
    res_str = x.group()
    out_list.append(re.split('(\s+), res_str))
df = pd.DataFrame(out_list)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('somefile.xlsx', 'xlsxwriter') #Only grabs one value then quits
df.to_excel(writer, 'blah')
writer.save()
```

If there is still only one thing in the data frame. You should check the length of out_list before you try to convert it. I am guessing it is only length of 1 because below works just fine. In this case check you regex or data.

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df
   0
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
```

Comment: Thanks ak_slick,
Yes its only a length of 1, how can I fix that or is it even possible?

Comment: See update about appending list.  Before you were overwriting it each time. Do you have an example of source data?